# Old screenless notebook with ubuntu v.14: sudo password

Tags: uninstall, password-recovery

I'm trying to install a linux on a small notebook. I got it because the integrated screen was broken. I removed the screen and installed Ubuntu 14 (at this time).
But it was a few years ago, and now I don't remember my sudo password... (classic).

I've been trying to install a new distro in order to recover a fully working linux environment. So I created a bootable usb flash drive. The only problem is that I can't display the BIOS on my secondary screen in order to boot on the USB flash drive, and install the new Linux.
All the other solution (boot with Grub, install a new distro directly from the terminal, etc...) requires a sudo password (Grub is not installed btw).

I don't have any more ideas.

EDIT:
The iso wasn't properly installed on the USB flash drive. So it is now working
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the hard disk and attach it to a different computer, then reinstall to the new hard disk (or just change the password, or just wipe the drive), finally replace the hard disk in the original notbook.

Alternatively, try different external monitors - you may find one which is happy to show the BIOS screen.